# Phpbarcode - a barcode generator script can't save image

Tags: php, image, barcode, barcode-printing

I am using [this barcode generator class](http://www.barcodebakery.com) to generate barcodes. Everything works nice, but the output can't be saved. When I inspect element, it shows me this

[image]

Basically, there is no image.

Here is the code

```
 <?php
    require($_SERVER['WROOT'].'/core/init.php');

    if ( !Input::isPost('new-barcode') || Input::post('new-barcode') == '' ) {
        Go::to('products');
    }

    $barcode = Input::post('new-barcode');

    require_once(ROOT.'core/barcode/class/BCGFontFile.php');
    require_once(ROOT.'core/barcode/class/BCGColor.php');
    require_once(ROOT.'core/barcode/class/BCGDrawing.php');
    require_once(ROOT.'core/barcode/class/BCGcode11.barcode.php');

    $colorFront = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
    $colorBack = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);
    $font = new BCGFontFile(ROOT.'core/barcode/font/Arial.ttf', 18);

    $code = new BCGcode11();
    $code->setScale(2);
    $code->setThickness(50);
    $code->setForegroundColor($colorFront);
    $code->setBackgroundColor($colorBack);
    $code->setFont($font);
    $code->parse($barcode);

    $drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $colorBack);
    $drawing->setBarcode($code);
    $drawing->draw('test.png');

    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    $drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);

?>
```

The demo provided alongside the downloaded files works as intended and I can save the generated image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `style="-webkit-user-select: none"`. This prevents the user from being able to interact with the image. Otherwise, everything is working fine. From this code sample, I'm not totally sure what is adding that CSS style to the image... but that's your issue.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked this and within the browser I unchecked this option but the image is still 'not an image'. When I right click and 'Save image as..', nothing happens.

Comment: Any way you can put some demo output on the web so we can play with it?

Comment: That screenshot is of an image file displayed in chrome. Chrome adds that style when you right click on a lone image and select "Inspect Element"

Comment: Ah... so this screenshot is of the actual image file itself? That helps... I just looked at your live demo on the web. I am able to right-click the image with Chrome and say "save image as." Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for, but when you click 'Save image as..', it does not actually save, nothing happens. Are you able to save it ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to save it.

Comment: Well that is very strange. With chrome I can not save it, with FF I can but when I try to open it, it says the file is corrupted. Can you confirm that once saved you are able to open it ( I need to print it ) ? Also what version are you using of Chrome ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, I can save it. Yes, it opens. Yes, everything is working fine. Yes, this is Chrome (Version 32.0.1700.76 m).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have the same version but I am unable to save it. I don't know what the problem may be at this point. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use this : `$drawing->setFilename('directory/filename.png');` it's working good.

```
$drawing->setFilename('directory/filename.png');<br>
$drawing->finish($filetypes[$_GET['filetype']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to force the browser to download the image when the user clicks on a link to it, try adding `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=barcode.png");`

Comment: I just want to display the image and if the user decides he can save it or not, so I don't want to force the download.